# How do I get the native mongodb client from a jugglingdb adapter during compoundjs initialization?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, compoundjs, jugglingdb

I'm working with compoundjs and using the mongodb adapter of jugglingdb. I've been retrieving and reusing the [native mongodb client](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) in the controllers by doing the following:

```
var db = compound.orm._schemas[0].client;
```

This works great, as I am able to use functions that mongodb supports, such as `.collection(name)` and `.find()` on top of that. However, when I create an initializer for compoundjs, `.client` is empty, but it looks like `_schemas[0]` isn't. For example:

```
module.exports = function (compound) {
    var db = compound.orm._schemas[0].client; // _schemas[0] isn't empty as .client was reached.
    db.collection('collection'); // Throws: TypeError: Cannot call method 'collection' of undefined
};
```

How do I retrieve the native mongodb client from the jugglingdb adapter, without recreating the connection myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the `connected` event from the JugglingDB event emitter.

```
module.exports = function (compound) {
    compound.orm._schemas[0].once('connected', function () {
        var db = compound.orm._schemas[0].client;
        db.collection('Module');
    });
};
```

**Explanation:**

When JugglingDB loads an adapter, it passes in a finished callback, which [triggers the connected event](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb/blob/master/lib/schema.js#L121). When loading the mongo adapter, the adapter uses an [async call](https://github.com/jugglingdb/mongodb-adapter/blob/master/lib/mongodb.js#L79) to connect to the database, which could cause initializers to run before the adapter is fully connected.